# How to keep Thread variables in jmeter when multiple Threads are running in parallel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, jmeter, beanshell

I have my **multiple threads Running in parallel**.
Any request can get fired from any thread that too multiple times.
I have stored my request variables in beanshell using **vars.put()**.
I have retrieved this variables in another beanshell using **vars.get()**.
but when Thread runs in parallel , I want that while retriving a variable it 
should retrive the value which of current Thread.
Somewhat like in java how we use **this** keyword and get current object's property.
how can I do this?

```
int ThreadNum = ctx.getThreadNum();
String[] Request_values= new String[Request_variables.length];
```

> how will I conacat the thread number to the Request_values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can put your string array using **vars.putObject("","")**;
>   at thhis time you can concat your thread number at keyname.

```
int ThreadNum = ctx.getThreadNum();
String[] Request_values= new String[Request_variables.length];
vars.putObject("Key_"+ThreadNum ,Request_values);
```

Answer (score 4):

JMeter Variables are basically [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) therefore you don't need to do anything.

If you need to access the value of variable of Thread 1 in Thread 2 you can use [${__threadNum} function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) as a prefix or postfix to append current thread number to the JMeter Variable name.

Comment: https://github.com/susiexd/MyJmeter/issues/2   Can you please refer to this link? I have posted my assertions over there.

Comment: Thank you so much . I am Trying this one